# How to block an ip address without DNS resolution in iptables

Tags: iptables

My server is under attacked by exim brute force with a fake ip:

```
2014-05-31 16:05:09 login authenticator failed for ([my_public_ip]) [178.41.179.50]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=grey)
```

I have some rules to block the origin 178.41.179.50 ip but no success.
I try to block the incoming traffic with fake source with my public ip like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s my_public_ip -j DROP
```

But it seem take resolve my public ip to DNS instead.So it does not work.

Any help ?

Comment: Is the rule the first rule in iptables to make sure that it is run? Did you run ip-tables save? Try removing the -i eth0 param.

Comment: Yes, i can see with "iptables -L" and it list the 178.41.179.50 and my server domain name in the DROP list

Comment: `iptables -L` will try to fetch RDNS for IPs in listing by defaul. Add `-n` flag to disable it. If you added rule with IP, it will work with IP. It's not so easy to block domain with iptables.

Also, if you are trying to block packets from `178.41.179.50`, then why do you have `my_public_ip` in `-s` flag? What you wrote literally means `drop packets that come on eth0 from my_public_ip`. I guess you should try changing it to `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 178.41.179.50 -j DROP`

Comment: Yes, attacker is trying to fake my public ip .I have both rules but it does not work: iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 178.41.179.50 -j DROP and iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s my_public_ip -j DROP